# Upload file and Deploy Function- Shiny

Tags: r, function, shiny, shinyjs

I have a dynamic function in R where the file is uploaded and the function is run. The same thing I have to do on shiny but the only difference is the file should be uploaded on shiny and the function should run backend.

I tried using setting an upload button to file upload and then got stuck.

```
# file_to_upload- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
age<- c(23,45,67,62,50)
ht<- c(5.3,6.0,4.9,5.0,5.5)
df<- data.frame(age, ht)
func_to_run<- function(value=0.5){
  df<- df$age+value
  return(df)
}
func_to_run()
```

The output is as expected but the same file should be uploaded on the shiny app not in R console.

Comment: See `?shiny::fileInput`.

Comment: That isn't working. Can you share the code?

Comment: There's an example in `?shiny::fileInput` and it works.